# How do I convert a pre-existing site to a Composer-managed application?

Tags: drush, composer

The latest Drush 9.x version recommends that Drupal 8 sites will be built using Composer, with Drush listed as a dependency. However, when you install Composer and Drush globally per step #1 on http://docs.drush.org/en/master/install and then proceed to step #2 Installing Drush Launcher and then try to run Drush on a pre-existing Drupal website (e.g. `drush --version`), then you will get:

> Drush Launcher Version: 0.6.0
>   The Drush launcher could not find a Drupal site to operate on. Please do *one* of the following:
>
> - Navigate to any where within your Drupal project and try again.
> - Add --root=/path/to/drupal so Drush knows where your site is located.

How do I get around this problem, and make Drush work with pre-existing Drupal sites?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Follow
  https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/using-composer-to-manage-drupal-site-dependencies#managing-existing-site
- Copy-paste method:

  1. Install [Composerize Drupal](https://github.com/grasmash/composerize-drupal) with `composer global require grasmash/composerize-drupal` command;
  2. Run `cd path/to/drupal/project/repo && composer composerize-drupal
     --composer-root=[repo-root]    --drupal-root=[drupal-root]` where `[composer-root]` is the root directory of your project where .git is located and    `[drupal-root]` is the Drupal root where index.php is located.
- Manually restructure pre-existing Drupal projects per discussion between Norman and Moshe on https://github.com/drush-ops/drush-launcher/issues/33
- Rebuild the code base from scratch, see https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2018/converting-non-composer-drupal-codebase-use-composer

Comment: Should I create a new empty git repository before I migrate an existing Drupl 8 site, or should I initialize the git repository with the `drupal-composer/drupal-project:8.x-dev` template first and then overwrite the `web` directory?

Answer (score 3):

In case you use Drupal7, I did

```
drush pm-list --status="enabled" --no-core --fields=name,version > modules.txt
while read line; do comp=`echo $line | sed 's/.*(\(.*\))/\1/' - | sed 's/7\.x\-//' - | awk '$1=$1'`; echo \"drupal\/`echo $comp | awk '{ print $1 }'`\"\:\ \"`echo $comp | awk '{ print $2 }'`\"; done < modules.txt
```

You can cut&paste your modules list directly into your composer :D