# Should I not update from 8.4.2 straight to 8.6.13?

Tags: updating

Due to someone leaving the company I work for I was handed the "webmaster" duties of a website hosted off-site running on Drupal 8.4.2. When I first logged in to the admin panel I discovered a host of problems, the most important one being the security updates. I first thought it wouldn't be much of a problem, as the hosting company has the handy interface to install and update/upgrade a number of web applications. But it turns out the that person before me installed Drupal manually (I have no idea why) so I'm wary of doing the "one click install" of Drupal 8.6.13. Furthermore, I don't know enough about Drupal to know if it would be a bad idea to update from 8.4.2 directly to 8.6.13. Would it be a better idea to first update to 8.5.14 and then to 8.6.13?

I've read through a lot of the release notes (8.5.0, 8.5.14, 8.6.0, 8.6.13, & a few others in that range) so I'm aware of the need to upgrade to PHP 7.3. I'm also very comfortable with the command line (it's running on Linux) and I've read (and re-read) the Drupal docs for updating via the command line.

I contacted the hosting provider with this same question but their "yeah, it'll be fine" answer to using their "one-click installer" wasn't very reassuring, so I thought I'd pose the question here before I take the plunge. Thanks for any words of advice or warning.

Comment: download a copy and try the updates locally before you do anything in production.

Comment: Thanks. That did cross my mind earlier. Perhaps I'll bring in my Linux laptop from home on Monday and give that a shot.

Comment: Update straight, you'll be fine.

Comment: You might also want to consider composerizing your drupal installation but do so in a controlled environment (testing server or your local computer) https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/258452/how-do-i-convert-a-pre-existing-site-to-a-composer-managed-application.  This will help you save time with updates in the future.

Comment: Keep i mind that Drupal 8.4.2 predates SA-CORE-2018-002 and SA-CORE-2018-004.  If your site is public, there is a chance it is compromised.

Comment: Composer was already installed but drush wasn't so I tried multiple times to install drush but it failed every time. This is a relatively small site and I've already wasted enough time so since I had a full backup of the site I decided to try the one-click install. I wished I had done this from the beginning, as I was presented with the option of starting with a fresh install or of importing an existing one. I still did incremental updates (8.4.2 -> 8.4.10 -> 8.5.0 -> 8.5.14 -> 8.6.0 -> 8.6.13), checking the site after each one, and everything went fine.

Comment: P.S. - Per mpdonadio's comment, I'm now reading through all of the SA-CORE-2018-002 & SA-CORE-2018-004 docs and starting the forensics journey. Thanks to all of you for your advice.